# SwiftUI: Path's coordinateSpace

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ios-simulator, swiftui

So I've got the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var draggingLocation = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var startLocation = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var dragging = false

    var body: some View {
        let GR = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onEnded { value in
                self.dragging = false
                self.draggingLocation = CGPoint.zero
                self.startLocation = CGPoint.zero
            }
            .onChanged { value in
                if !self.dragging {
                    self.dragging = true
                }
                if self.startLocation == CGPoint.zero {
                    self.startLocation = value.startLocation
                }
                self.draggingLocation = value.location
            }

        return ZStack {
            if self.dragging {
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.startLocation.x-5, y: self.startLocation.y-5))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.draggingLocation.x-5, y: self.draggingLocation.y+5))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.draggingLocation.x+5, y: self.draggingLocation.y-5))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.startLocation.x+5, y: self.startLocation.y+5))
                }
                .fill(Color.black)
            }

            Circle()
            .fill(self.dragging ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .gesture(GR)
            .offset(
                x: 75,
                y: 75
            )

            Circle()
            .fill(self.dragging ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .gesture(GR)
            .offset(
                x: -75,
                y: -75
            )
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Which results in this behavior:

[image: ios]

I'd like to be able to drag the edge out from one circle and into the other, the problem of course is that the coordinate space of the `Path` is relative to the gray box (`ContentView`) and not global. A `Path` has a property `coordinateSpace` in the documentation but there's very little information how to use it, and googling the term with SwiftUI literally returns three results, all of which are really just links to Apple's currently sparse docs. Anyone have an idea on how to best approach this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Coordinate spaces come in three flavours: .local, .global and .named. The first two are obvious. The third, **named** coordinate spaces, are extremely useful in cases like yours. They are also useful in combination with GeometryReader. For more details on that, check https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/

Named coordinate spaces let you express a coordinate of one view, in the coordinate space of another. For that, SwiftUI let you specify a name for a view's coordinate space. Then, in other places of your code, you can make a reference of it. In your example, naming the coordinate of your ZStack is the way to go.

Here's the refactored code:

*Note: I moved the Path below, only so that it draws in front of the circles. And also, pay attention to the first Path, which is only there to prevent what I think is a bug in ZStack.*

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var draggingLocation = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var startLocation = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var dragging = false

    var body: some View {
        let GR = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .named("myCoordinateSpace"))
            .onEnded { value in
                self.dragging = false
                self.draggingLocation = CGPoint.zero
                self.startLocation = CGPoint.zero
        }
        .onChanged { value in
            if !self.dragging {
                self.dragging = true
            }

            if self.startLocation == CGPoint.zero {
                self.startLocation = value.startLocation
            }
            self.draggingLocation = value.location
        }

        return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {

            Circle()
                .fill(self.dragging ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .overlay(Text("Circle 1"))
                .gesture(GR)
                .offset(x: 75, y: 75)

            Circle()
                .fill(self.dragging ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .overlay(Text("Circle 2"))
                .gesture(GR)
                .offset(x: 200, y: 200)

            if self.dragging {
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.startLocation.x-5, y: self.startLocation.y-5))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.draggingLocation.x-5, y: self.draggingLocation.y+5))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.draggingLocation.x+5, y: self.draggingLocation.y-5))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.startLocation.x+5, y: self.startLocation.y+5))
                }
                .fill(Color.black)
            }

        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "myCoordinateSpace")
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As a side note, what’s the best way to programmatically tell if the edge was ‘dropped’ over one circle or the other? Maybe without comparing drawn locations because that seems messy to say the least.

Comment: You're welcome. It seems SwiftUI has DragAndDrop support, but only for macOS (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dropoperation). I'm hopeful they will eventually extend it to iOS. Better sooner than later.

Comment: I updated the code. I though there was a bug in ZStack, but it was doing the right thing. I missed a couple of alignment parameters. For a detail of the changes you can view the edit differences of the post.

Comment: Bummer, yeah hopefully they add it to iOS soon. Extending this a bit if there need to be two named coordinateSpace's, it seems to be based off the circles size and in the top left, not quite what I was expecting: Gif: https://imgur.com/a/R0E0p5h -- Code: https://gist.github.com/adammenges/c83f357888377c2ad3fa6494090dddd0

Comment: In addition to .coordinateSpace(), you may profit from using anchor preferences (Anchor<CGRect> and Anchor<CGPoint>). They are opaque types that hold geometry and coordinate space together. You use a GeometryProxy subscript function to "decode" them. It's an extensive topic, but I've written a whole article about it. Here's the link: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/